# How to track tasks in project and differentiate between duration and percentage of a resources day

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, tasks

I have a project with a slew of tasks.  Let's say for the sake of example I have 5 tasks and these 5 tasks will take 5 calendar days to execute.  But, due to the nature of the task, a resource can only work 2 hours a day on the task due to the nature of the task.

Is there a way to create a task in project such that is has a duration, but does not fully impact the resource over that duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not.  Tasks by themselves know nothing about how much work a resource or resources will perform.  However, you can assign resource such that they don't work "fulltime" on the task.  A couple of options:

- Create the 5 day duration task and temporarily set it as Fixed
  Duration.
- Use the Task Form to assign the resource and enter 10 hours
  of work.

Project will calculate the Peak units necessary to spread the 10 hours of work evenly across the 5 day duration.
I would then, personally, return the task to either Fixed Units, or Fixed work.

Comment: This is essentially the work-around I discovered.  Set the duration, then i the resource view reduce the amount of hours the task will take.